# SIGSEGV on termination after procces called QWidget.setParent()

Tags: c++, qt

I try to code a qt widget for popping up a dialog when trying to open a file.
I currently came so far:

```
class FileDialog : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    QLineEdit Browser1;
public:
    QWidget Dialog;
    FileDialog();
    ~FileDialog();
};


FileDialog::FileDialog()
{
    Dialog.setFixedSize(600, 250);
    Browser1.setParent(&Dialog); // SIGSEGV comes since I have added this line. Uncommenting fixes it.
    return;
}

FileDialog::~FileDialog()
{
    return;
}
```

But when I tried to add the text field for the path into the widget all is working as expected until I terminate the application, after that (in case I'm in debug mode) the programm receives a `SIGSEGV`.
When I comment it out again I don't get any error anymore.

So what do I have forgotten, what has to be reminded when adding a widget as child of another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a widget as child of another, the parent widget, according to the Qt architecture, takes ownership over its child widget and will try to destroy it when you terminate the application. In the same time your `Browser1` is the member variable of the `FileDialog` class, which will also try to destroy the same object in its destructor. Here is where the problem comes from.

As a solution I would recommend:

- Use pointers for Qt objects,
- Maintain the parent/child relationship,
- Use layouts to construct the GUI